# Images not sitting properly within my Bootstrap divs

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to fit my images in my responsive grid design, but try as I might, it doesn't work. My images are sizes 375*250px with exception to one, which is 745*250px

I have put images of what I would like the layout to be, but what it actually turns out to be [like this (for larger screens)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad2V5.jpg)
instead of [like this (desired for larger screens)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBRxb.jpg)

My code is below - been trying viewport widths for the divs containing the images, but it doesn't seem to work - the images seem to be overflowing the grid area defined for them.

```
<div class="row" id="picture">
    <div class ="col-md-8 col-lg-8" id="seeBig">
    <img src="see.jpg" />
    </div> <!--See Big-->

   <div class ="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="eat">
   <img src="eat.jpg" />
   </div> <!--Eat -->

  <div class ="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="do">
  <img src="do.jpg" />
  </div> <!--Do -->

  <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" id="seeSmall">
  <img src="see.jpg" />
  </div> <!--See Small-->

  <div class ="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="stay">
  <img src="stay.jpg" />
  </div> <!--Stay -->

  <div class ="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="shop">   
  <img src="shop.jpg" />

</div> <!--Picture-->
```

This is the CSS

```
#seeSmall,#eat,#stay,#shop,#do, #seeBig{
border: solid 1px black;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
overflow:hidden;
}
@media all and (min-width: 992px) {

#seeSmall{
    display: none;
    }
#seeBig {
    width:60%vw;
    height:20%vw;


}   
#eat , #stay ,#shop ,#do {
    width:30%vw;
    height:20%vw;


    }

}


@media all and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {


#seeBig{
    display:none;

}
#seeSmall {
    width:90%vw;
    height:20%vw;

    }
#stay {
    width:45%vw;
    height:20%vw;

    }
#shop {

    width:45%vw;
    height:20%vw;

    }
#eat {

    width:30%vw;
    height:20%vw;

}
#do {
    width:60%vw;
    height:20%vw;

   }

}

@media all and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 250px) {

#seeBig{
    display:none;
    }
#seeSmall {

    width:85%vw;
    height:17%vw;
    max-width:100%;
    }
#stay {
    width:42.5%vw;
    height:17%vw;
    max-width:100%;
    }
#shop  {
    width:42.5%vw;
    height:17%vw;
    max-width:100%;
    }
#eat {
    width:28%vw;
    height:17%vw;
    max-width:100%;
    }
#do {

    width:57%vw;
    height:17%vw;
    max-width:100%;
   }
}
```

Comment: @Saurabh is right, you need to wrap each set in a row. Also you use redundant classes (`col-md-4 col-lg-4`) should just be `cold-md-4` since it will remain 4/12 in large screens too. And `img` tags do need to be closed in HTML5. here is a basic demo: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/z8dupbsL/

Comment: I also recommend running your CSS code through a validator. So many errors...

Comment: Thing is it is a "dynamic" row, where when the screen goes smaller, the "See" image pops below "Eat" and "Do" with Eat and Do occupying the top row in the ratio 2:1  - hence splitting it into rows would not help :(

Comment: Or would the display =
none help with the row binding ? Bit of a novice here - hence the queries. Will put my code through a validator as well :/

Comment: Hi - there is a small 2px divide between the 2 rows -especially when the screen is larger in size - any workaround for that ? Please do have a look at the revised code I've placed as an answer in this post. Thanks for the suggestion - it worked really well !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using simple bootstrap classes it is quite difficult to use those type of grids. For that purpose you have to use **row-wise** structure to fit those images in your container, like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8"><img class="img-responsive" src"big_horizontal.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img class="img-responsive" src"another_img1.jpg"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><img class="img-responsive" src"another_img2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img class="img-responsive" src"another_img3.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img class="img-responsive" src"another_img4.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

**I assume here, height of all images is same and width of a big horizontal image is 2 times that of small image**

but this type of **row-wise** structure gets messy when there are so many images on a single page. So for so many images, you may use plugin [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which is free and easy to use.**It is best suited for image gallery like structures.**

Comment: Hi - the row-wise approach worked ! I made 2 other img divs disappear with display:none and set margins, padding to 0 and it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use the built-in Bootstrap [responsive image class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images). This will allow your images to scale to the parent element. To do so for your example code, it is this simple:

```
<div class ="col-md-8 col-lg-8" id="seeBig">
    <img src="see.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image Title">
</div> <!--See Big-->
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the height of #seeBig is pushing the #do and #stay down. Is there a link to the page where we could see what else is going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the img tags a max-width: 100%

Answer (score 0):

While I have split it into 2 rows as suggested by @Saurabh and @Aziz (thanks folks!) It results in the bigger size having a 2px white space between the 2 rows at the breakpoint [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXIRY.jpg)
I have done this :

```
<div class="row" id="pictureBig">
<div class ="col-md-8" id="seeBig">
<img src="see.jpg" >
</div> <!--See Big-->

<div class ="col-md-4" id="eatBig">
<img src="eat.jpg"> 
</div> <!--Eat Big -->
</div> <!--Picture Big-->
<div class ="col-xs-6" id="eatSmall">
<img src="eat.jpg">
</div> <!--Eat Small -->
<div class ="col-xs-6" id="doSmall">
<img src="do.jpg" >
</div> <!--DoSmall -->
<div class ="row" id="pictureSmall">

<div class ="col-md-4" id="doBig">
<img src="do.jpg" >
</div> <!--DoBig -->

<div class ="col-xs-12" id="seeSmall">  
<img src="see.jpg" >
</div> <!--See Small-->

<div class ="col-xs-6 col-md-4 " id="stay">
<img src="stay.jpg" />
</div> <!--Stay -->

<div class ="col-xs-6 col-md-4 " id="shop">
<img src="shop.jpg" >
</div> <!--Shop -->
</div> <!-- Row picture Small-->
```

With an updated CSS:

```
#seeSmall,#eatSmall,#stay,#shop,#doSmall, #seeBig,#doBig,#eatBig{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#seeSmall img,#eatSmall img,#stay img,#shop img,#doSmall img, #seeBig img,  #eatBig img, #doBig img{
flex-shrink:0;
min-width:100%;
min-height:100%;

}

#pictureBig, #pictureSmall{

border: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
@media all and (min-width: 992px) {

#seeSmall , #eatSmall,#doSmall{
    display: none;
    }

#seeBig {
    width:60%vw;
    height:20%vw;
    max-width:100%;

}   
#eatBig , #stay ,#shop ,#doBig {
    width:30%vw;
    height:20%vw;
    max-width:100%;

  }

}


 @media all and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {

   #seeBig, #eatBig,#doBig{
    display:none;

   }
    #seeSmall {
    width:90%vw;
    height:20%vw;
    max-width:100%;
     }
    #stay ,#eatSmall,#shop,#doSmall {
     width:45%vw;
     height:20%vw;
     max-width:100%;
     }

    }

@media all and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 250px) {

#seeBig, #eatBig, #doBig{
    display:none;
    }
#seeSmall {

    width:85%vw;
    height:17%vw;
    max-width:100%;
    }
#stay ,#eatSmall,#shop,#doSmall{
    width:42.5%vw;
    height:17%vw;
    max-width:100%;
    }

}
```